# Error when install Cordova on Mac

Tags: cordova

I was trying to install Cordova by using npm, but it took more than one hour, and then I gave up. Later I tried to follow the instruction from http://cordova.apache.org/, and the error occurred when I executed `npm install -g ios-deploy`.

Here is what I get in command line:

> YangHenrydeMacBook-Pro:~ Yong$ sudo npm install -g ios-deploy
>   npm WARN lifecycle ios-deploy@1.8.3~preinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) ios-deploy@1.8.3 ./src/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ios-deploy-fbfd9f76b9a8909271fae167aab47715
>   npm ERR! Darwin 14.4.0
>   npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ios-deploy"
>   npm ERR! node v5.1.1
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
>   npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy
>   npm ERR! code ENOENT
>   npm ERR! errno -2
>   npm ERR! syscall chmod
>   npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy'
>   npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>   npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>   npm ERR! enoent
>   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /Users/Yong/npm-debug.log

Could anyone give me some hints? Thanks!

Comment: I know this question is old, but If you found the solution, please share, i'm having the same issue on my mac.

Comment: This works for me: sudo npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true

Answer (score 2):

For completeness sake, @Sam003's answer is right, using the `--unsafe-perm=true` is the recommended-by-node way to install modules under MacOS 10.11 and later.

From an nmp install:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!! WARNING: You are on OS X 10.11 El Capitan or greater, you may need to add the
!!!! WARNING:   `--unsafe-perm=true` flag when running `npm install`
!!!! WARNING:   or else it will fail.
!!!! WARNING: link:
!!!! WARNING:   https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy#os-x-1011-el-capitan
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```