# sudo ionic run android not working

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to run a hybrid app on my android phone using ionic using the following command:

> sudo ionic run android

However I keep receiving this error :

> Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting
>   setting it manually. Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'.
>   Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

I have already added platform tools & tools to PATH updated `ANDROID_HOME` to point to my sdk root.

The `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable shows up when I run `env` and the `PATH` has the tools and platform tools too. Additionally I can execute `android` too. It launches the SDK Manager as expected.

Details:

`ANDROID_HOME`: /home/user/Android/Sdk
`$PATH`: /home/user/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/user/Android/Sdk/platform-tools

Please help! This is driving me up the wall!

Comment: which OS are you using? Also could you post those path and android_home variables value?

Comment: Did you add the android platform also in `sudo`? I think it has permission problems going on. It is greatly discouraged to use `sudo` when running with cordova/ionic.

Comment: @Gandhi I am using Ubuntu 16.04. @Dar I may have added the android platform in sudo. Could it be the problem? When I looked up the `env` variables after `sudo su`, `ANDROID_HOME` didn't show up. `android` wasn't working either.

Comment: @VineetKaushik can you try removing the android platform and then adding it back without sudo? `sudo ionic platform remove android`, then `ionic platform add android` then `ionic build android --verbose` to see if it builds okay

Comment: @VineetKaushik Try executing the following commands: export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android-sdk/tools
export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk Suggest to have a look at this link - https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/09/install-android-cordova-ionic-framework-ubuntu/

Comment: @Dar it says permission denied `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/configstore/index.js:53
throw err;`

Comment: @Gandhi yep I've seen that tutorial already.

Comment: @Dar it turns out it was a problem with `sudo` after all. I found a solution to it.

Comment: @VineetKaushik Good to hear. If you need a workaround without using `sudo` at all: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37535726/2036808

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/35960516/6449750

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit for this goes to @heemayl on AskUbuntu.

https://askubuntu.com/a/783805/247116

> `sudo` sanitizes the environment and by default only keeps certain
> environment variables available with modifying the values of some
> (e.g. PATH).
>
> You can pass the variable ANDROID_HOME manually:
>
> > sudo ANDROID_HOME="/actual/path" ionic run android
>
> Or preserve the current environment:
>
> > sudo -E ionic run android